# Gradle build takes too long while creating a new project

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Everytime I create a new project, gradle build takes too long to finish for about 20 to 25 minutes. It is usually on "Gradle: Resolve dependencies ':app_debugAndroidTestxxx'" but when running my program it doesn't take that long only when creating a new project.

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWQNK.png).

Comment: What platform are you on? Does your system matches min requirements?

Comment: @VidorVistrom I have 8gb of ram, i3 4130, windows 7 64 bit and 500 gb of hdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Internet connection, try to create a new Android Studio project in offline mode. Because some dependencies might be take time to install from internet. So in offline mode, it pick downloaded dependencies from cache.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It fixed my problem. From 25 minutes of gradle build time to seconds.